# How to set timezone in Qt?

Tags: qt, timezone, qdatetime, qtime

Can someone show me how to set time zone in Qt? Currently I am using the linux system() call to set the time zone, but this is not reflecting in currentTime() API of Qt. There is a setTimeZone() API in Qt 5 and above but I have no idea how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to display times in the system timezone, or do you want to actually change the timezone of the system?

Comment: change the timezone of the system itself.

Comment: There's no API for that in Qt. That's system configuration, usually nothing a normal application is (or should be) concerned with.

Comment: what about the QDateTine::setTimeZone() API? What does it do?

Comment: It's sets the timezone for that particular QDateTime object, representing a date and time. It has nothing to do with the system timezone.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Frank in the comments, there is no API in Qt to directly change the system timezone. Using `timedatectl` is one way to go.

However instead of a `system()` call, `QProcess` could be used like this for an example timezone:

```
auto timezone = QString("Europe/Paris");
auto command = QString("timedatectl set-timezone ") + timezone;
auto ret = QProcess::execute(command);
if (ret != 0) {
    qDebug("timedatectl failed : %d", ret);
}
```

If there is already a QTimeZone object in use, the command can be assembled like this:

```
auto timezoneObj = QTimeZone();

// process timezoneObj

if (!timezoneObj.isValid()) {
    qDebug("invalid timezone qobject");
    return;
}

auto timezone = timezoneObj.id();
auto command = QString("timedatectl set-timezone ") + timezone;
auto ret = QProcess::execute(command);
if (ret != 0) {
    qDebug("timedatectl failed : %d", ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using QProcess I'd probably recommend to use QDBus instead.

qdbus command line call:

```
qdbus --system org.freedesktop.timedate1 /org/freedesktop/timedate1 org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetTimezone Europe/Berlin false
```

Qt code:

```
QDBusInterface timedated("org.freedesktop.timedate1", "/org/freedesktop/timedate1", "org.freedesktop.timedate1", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
QDBusPendingReply<> setTz = timedated.callWithArgumentList(QDBus::Block, "SetTimeZone", {"Europe/Berlin", false});
```